# Quality reduction is not working in files api

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, image-compression, html5-filesystem

i write a small snippet for optimizing large images.i write a code

```
var f = evt.target.files[0];
var r = new FileReader();
r.onloadend = function (e) {
    var img = new Image();
    console.log('coming here also');
    var contents = e.target.result;
    console.log("Got the file.n" + "name: " + f.name + "n" + "type: " + f.type + "n" + "size: " + f.size + " bytesn");
    var mime_type = "image/png";
    var cvs = document.createElement('canvas');
    var im = new Image();
    im.onload = function () {
        cvs.width = im.width;
        cvs.height = im.height;
        var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d").drawImage(im, 0, 0);
        var newImageData = cvs.toDataURL(mime_type, 0.3);
        console.log(newImageData);
    }
    im.src = r.result;
};
r.readAsDataURL(f);
```

but i am getting image of same size.i am uploading an image of 34.9 kb getting with same size.please tell why its not optimizing image ??

Answer (score 0):

Only mime_type='image/jpeg' allows specified compression (not .png types).

Comment: no  in png images also i can see compression problem resolved.will put my answer 2 days later right now busy